# Add js to remove ribbon on sharepoint through designer 2013

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I want to remove **s4-ribbonrow** from my webpage through designer 2013 using javascript. I don't have access to modify master page.

I've tried this:

```
<style type="text/css">
#s4-ribbonrow {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

But it's not working. Is some specific holder to place this script?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The found code works pretty well. But you need to add these lines inside the asp content.

Find by below into the master page:

`<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">`

Then do something like this:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
  <style type="text/css">
    #s4-ribbonrow {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since i've got no access to master page, it must be modified through javascript. Tried this and worked

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('s4-ribbonrow').style.visibility = 'hidden';
</script>
```